Why does type inference via generic function parameter to return type not work
I had a specific function to map from an array to a single item. Now I want to map it based on the discriminator, so I am trying to implement a more generic function.
I have a function with input parameter of a union type which has a discriminator.
Another parameter is the discriminator of the union['type']. Why can't TypeScript infer the return type based on that parameter?
Is it just not possible for the TypeScript to infer this type or may this be just an unsupported feature?
type Bar = {
    name: string
    type: 'Bar'
}

type Foo = {
    name: string
    type: 'Foo'
}

type Item = Bar | Foo;

declare const returnI: <I extends Item>(items: Item[], type: I['type']) => I | undefined
    

const lala = returnI([], 'Foo') // expected to be type Foo.
//    ^? const lala: Item | undefined

Playground
(version 5.4.5).

This sort of inference was never implemented in the language; there's an old PR at ms/TS#20216 which would have done this, and there's a more recent PR at ms/TS#53017; it's not clear if it will make it into the language.  Until then you need to refactor as this playground link shows. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz or without the ItemMap: <T extends Item['type']>(items: Item[], type: T) => Item & { type: T } | undefined

@jcalz I am mainly looking for logically explained reasons why A: This cant work ever. Or B: Why this isnt implemented yet. Given your explanation and references, it seems that this feature would be possible but just isnt adopted due to lack of popularity? Seema odd to me since this is a fairly "simple" use case which should be used more often, or not?

@Bergi interesting solution, I will play around with it. Thanks.

The use case is usually well-served by inferring the discriminating property type, not by inferring the union member. My version and the intersection version by Bergi works that way. Trying to infer the union member is reasonable but not considered vital to be implemented. Anyway I'm pretty sure I went over this in my first comment; is there anything I'm missing about your situation? Or should I go ahead and write a full answer?

@jcalz I think your explanation does suffice for now. Thank you.

see linked q/a for more information.
